# Dl4J compilation errors on beta-7

Tags: java, compiler-errors, version, dl4j

I have some compiler errors when trying to build a `MultiLayerConfiguration` in Dl4J (java). They are just fine, according to the docs and examples GitHub repository.

I am using NetBeans IDE, with Dl4J 1.0.0 beta-7. My JDK is set to 11. When I have the exact same code on beta-6, there are no problems, but on beta-7 it seems that there is no way whatsoever to get around these errors.

This project (Iris classifier) is just one of the projects in the Dl4J GitHub example repository that will not work as-is with Dl4J 1.0.0-beta-7 It complains about the very same things listed above.

```java
//...
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.RecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.csv.CSVRecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.split.FileSplit;
import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.MultiLayerConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.DenseLayer;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.OutputLayer;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.weights.WeightInit;
import org.deeplearning4j.optimize.listeners.ScoreIterationListener;
import org.deeplearning4j.examples.utils.DownloaderUtility;
import org.nd4j.evaluation.classification.Evaluation;
import org.nd4j.linalg.activations.Activation;
import org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.DataSet;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.SplitTestAndTrain;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.iterator.DataSetIterator;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.preprocessor.DataNormalization;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.preprocessor.NormalizerStandardize;
import org.nd4j.linalg.learning.config.Sgd;
import org.nd4j.linalg.lossfunctions.LossFunctions;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * @author Adam Gibson
 */
@SuppressWarnings("DuplicatedCode")
public class IrisClassifier {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IrisClassifier.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception {

        //First: get the dataset using the record reader. CSVRecordReader handles loading/parsing
        int numLinesToSkip = 0;
        char delimiter = ',';
        RecordReader recordReader = new CSVRecordReader(numLinesToSkip,delimiter);
        recordReader.initialize(new FileSplit(new File(DownloaderUtility.IRISDATA.Download(),"iris.txt")));

        //Second: the RecordReaderDataSetIterator handles conversion to DataSet objects, ready for use in neural network
        int labelIndex = 4;     //5 values in each row of the iris.txt CSV: 4 input features followed by an integer label (class) index. Labels are the 5th value (index 4) in each row
        int numClasses = 3;     //3 classes (types of iris flowers) in the iris data set. Classes have integer values 0, 1 or 2
        int batchSize = 150;    //Iris data set: 150 examples total. We are loading all of them into one DataSet (not recommended for large data sets)

        DataSetIterator iterator = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader,batchSize,labelIndex,numClasses);
        DataSet allData = iterator.next();
        allData.shuffle();
        SplitTestAndTrain testAndTrain = allData.splitTestAndTrain(0.65);  //Use 65% of data for training

        DataSet trainingData = testAndTrain.getTrain();
        DataSet testData = testAndTrain.getTest();

        //We need to normalize our data. We'll use NormalizeStandardize (which gives us mean 0, unit variance):
        DataNormalization normalizer = new NormalizerStandardize();
        normalizer.fit(trainingData);           //Collect the statistics (mean/stdev) from the training data. This does not modify the input data
        normalizer.transform(trainingData);     //Apply normalization to the training data
        normalizer.transform(testData);         //Apply normalization to the test data. This is using statistics calculated from the *training* set


        final int numInputs = 4;
        int outputNum = 3;
        long seed = 6;


        log.info("Build model....");
        MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .seed(seed)
            .activation(Activation.TANH)
            .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
            .updater(new Sgd(0.1))
            .l2(1e-4)
            .list()
/*FAIL >*/  .layer(new DenseLayer.Builder().nIn(numInputs).nOut(3)
                .build())
            .layer(new DenseLayer.Builder().nIn(3).nOut(3)
                .build())
            .layer( new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
                .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX) //Override the global TANH activation with softmax for this layer
                .nIn(3).nOut(outputNum).build())
            .build();

        //run the model
        MultiLayerNetwork model = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
        model.init();
        //record score once every 100 iterations
        model.setListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(100));

        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++ ) {
            model.fit(trainingData);
        }

        //evaluate the model on the test set
        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(3);
        INDArray output = model.output(testData.getFeatures());
        eval.eval(testData.getLabels(), output);
        log.info(eval.stats());

    }

}
```

#### Errors:

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
com/dl4jtest/csv/IrisClassifier.java:[("FAIL" marker),17] method layer in class org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration.ListBuilder cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.Layer
  found: org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.DenseLayer
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/quickstart/modeling/feedforward/classification/IrisClassifier.java

Comment: Could you upload a standalone github project I could look at here? I can't reproduce this issue at all on either beta7 or the newer versions. Ideally the flow would be me using beta6, it runs fine. It uses beta7, it fails.
The only guess I have is you can technically declare indices like 0, new DenseLayer()...

but that isn't actually required.

Comment: @AdamGibson. I added the `IrisClassifier` project from the DL4J example repo.